# How does the data flow from webserver to webpage.

Tags: apache, webserver, web-deployment

I am in process of creating a new website. I have done my basic HTML/CSS/JQuery code to generate the webpage. The website is going to display images. Now my questions are around where the images are supposed to be stored and how to retrieve them. I did research but I am all over the place with the architecture.

My understanding is that HTML page will make a query to a web server (like Apache) and get the data/images back and display it? The function of the web server is to provide the data based on the query, is that right? Where is the data like jpeg images, their metadata, link between gallery and images would be stored? Is there another layer of DB somewhere? Would the architecture be HTML<-->Apache<-->DB ?

Or do I just put my images in a database and host the data their. Basically taking out Apache from the architecture? The queries are going to depend only on the current stage in the navigation tree (nothing user specific).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for DB to use images. It works more this way:

HTML <-> Apache <-> Image

because apache has the ability to deliver files.

Now, there are several differents way of working.
For example, the image can be load dynamically in a php files with images header. In this case, the scheme will be :

HTML <-> Apache <-> PHP <-> Image

To do it, you simply put your images in a folder where apache's user can access.

For example you can have the following structure in /var/www/sitename:

- index.html
- img / my_image.jpg

And in index.html

```
<img src="img/my_image.jpg" ... />
```

**Edit to answer you question :**

create a php script that will generate the json array, for example :

*page.php*

```
<?php
switch($_GET['link']){
    case 'link1':
        images_links = array(
           'path/to/img1',
           'path/to/img2',
           ...
        );
        break;
    case 'link2':
        images_links = array(
           'path/to/img3',
           'path/to/img4',
           ...
        );
        break;
}

echo json_encode(images_links);
?>
```

Let's guess your html is

```
<a>link1</a>
<a>link2</a>
<img class="imgToChange" src="..."/>
<img class="imgToChange" src="..."/>
...
```

Then you will add this javascript function to your html

```
function updateImages(clicked_link){
    // get the text of the link
    link_text = clicked_link.innerHTML;

    // send a request to page.php to get images's urls
    $.get( "path/to/page.php?link="+link_text, function( data ) {
     // data will be your json array
     images_links = data;

     // get a table of all images elements that can be changed
     var images = document.getElementsByClassName("imgToChange");

     // for each image in the json array
     for(var k=0; k<images_links.length; k++){
         images[k].src = images_links[k];
     }

    });
}
```

And you just have to call this function when a link is clicked

```
<a onclick="updateImages(this)">link1</a>
<a onclick="updateImages(this)">link2</a>
<img class="imgToChange" src="..."/>
<img class="imgToChange" src="..."/>
...
```

Comment: Thanks ! I would do more research on this.I do have one question right off top of my head if you don't mind answering. How would apache know which images to send? Lets say the HTML has 5 links. User clicks on link 1, HTML sends request to apache with parameter = link1. I would expect the apache server to send back a JSON array which would transform the webpage via jquery. The JSON would be filled up based on table(which would reside on apache server?) query. Am I on right track? So the table that has entries for images along with other information would reside on Apache?

Comment: Many Thanks! I will set up my Apache server on AWS and see how it goes!